# ionic v2 Button text align

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

In my ionic v2 app I have several buttons with a icon and a text inside. With v1 of Ionic it was possible to align the icon and the text inside the button with a parameter.

```
<a class="item item-icon-left item-assertive">
    <i class="icon ion-gear"></i>
    SomeTextForExample
</a>
```

For v2 i haven't found any parameter then 'icon-left', which adds only a little gap between the icon and the text. Anyway, content of the button stay's centered.

Here is my html code from v2:

```
<button ion-button block icon-left color="danger">
    <ion-icon name="car"></ion-icon>
    TextFoo
</button>
```

I've removed the ngFor and the click function for easier reading. Any possibilities for an easy solution?

Comment: not sure what the question is, but you can use `text-center`, `text-right`, `text-left`, `icon-left and` `icon-right`.

Answer (score 2):

As far as we don't have a "legal" way to solve it with the `item-end` or `icon-left` we can use some css for button:

```
<button ion-button block icon-left color="danger" class="btn-align">
    <ion-icon name="car"></ion-icon>
    TextFoo
</button>
```

and class is

```
.btn-align {
    .button-inner { /*< --- this class added automatically */
        justify-content: flex-start;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<button ion-button block icon-left color="danger">
    <ion-icon name="car"></ion-icon>
    TextFoo
</button>
```

this should work. Just make sure that you are giving a valid name in the `<ion-icon>'s` name property. ex: `<ion-icon name="star"></ion-icon>`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on android < v4.4